# Why does getSymbols.tiingo return error - RStudio

Tags: r, quantmod, stocks

I'm trying to download 120 S&P 500 stock data using `getSymbols.tiingo` from `quantmod` but it returned `Error:` without any explanations. When I merge it based on the close price, I get 66 stocks in the data frame.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
  library(quantmod)
  StockData = new.env()
  tickers <- as.character(read.csv('http://trading.chrisconlan.com/SPstocks_current.csv', stringsAsFactors = F,header = F)[1:120,1])
  StartDate = as.Date("2018-01-01")
  EndDate = as.Date("2018-08-31")
  API = "API"
  getSymbols.tiingo(tickers, env = StockData, from = StartDate, to = EndDate, api.key = API)

  Error:

  Stock_Adj_Data <- do.call(merge, eapply(StockData, Cl))
  ncol(Stock_Adj_Data)
  [1] 66
```

Comment: have you checked if stock 67 returns data from tiingo?

Comment: @phiver the downloaded stocks are random. They are not in order...

Comment: You do realise that the free API from tiingo only gives you the ability to access 500 Unique Symbols Per Month and a maximum of 500 Requests Per Hour? BTW, your source is a csv-file. Not much random in that. So if you get this error, investigate the ticker where it goes wrong. My guess is that your api hits some limit somewhere.

Comment: @phiver Yes, that's the reason I picked 120 rather than the full list. Thanks for your insight. I will investigate further.